# Changing inner html of div depending on selected dropdown option

Tags: javascript, events, select

Hello there I have looked across this forum looking for the answer to this. I am using a select element to determine the HTML of a given div. I tried doing this with the option element but after reading some responses to other questions was told it is not cross browser friendly. Some of these answers I found worked but when I tried to adapt the answer it all fell apart! I am new to Javascript and the below looks perfectly logical to me! (I am guessing its not).

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeFunc() {
            var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
            var y = document.getelementbyid("demo");
            if (selectedValue == "1") {
                y.innerhtml = "hello";
            } else if (selectedValue == "2") {
                y.innerhtml = "hello 1";
            } else if (selectedValue == "3") {
                y.innerhtml = "hello 2";
            } else if (selectedValue == "4") {
                y.innerhtml = "hello 3";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <select id="selectBox" onchange="changeFunc();">
        <option value="1">Option #1</option>
        <option value="2">Option #2</option>
        <option value="3">Option #3</option>
        <option value="4">Option #4</option>
    </select>
    <div id="demo"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you r looking for :  [fiddle link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ankittyagi/5a8vyaj6/1/)

```
<html>
<body>

<select id="selectBox" onchange="return myFunction();">
<option value="1">Option #1</option>
<option value="2">Option #2</option>
<option value="3">Option #3</option>
<option value="4">Option #4</option>
</select>
<div id="demo" ></div>
    <script>
function myFunction() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("selectBox");
    var selectedValue = ele.options[ele.selectedIndex].value;

    var y = document.getElementById("demo");
    if(selectedValue=="1"){
       y.innerHTML = "hello";
    }
    else if(selectedValue=="2"){
       y.innerHTML = "hello 1";
    }
    else if(selectedValue=="3"){
       y.innerHTML = "hello 2";
    }
    else if(selectedValue=="4"){
       y.innerHTML = "hello 3";
    }
}
    </script>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: provided the fiddle link too :)

Comment: Hello Tyagi and Chianh, thanks for your quick responses. Neither answer is working for me. I put the code example (Tyagi) straight in to my editor.

Comment: make sure you write your javascript at last inside body as shown above.